# Identação de chaves VS Code

Tags: visual-studio-code

O Visual Studio Code possui uma configuração nativa para alterar a identação das chaves (C#)?

Tenho instalada a extensão C# FixFormat, mas ao salvar o arquivo ele identa dessa forma:

```
public class teste {
}
```

gostaria que identasse dessa forma:

```
public class teste
{
}
```

Comment: Esse link te ajuda? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47352611/vs-code-doesnt-format-c-sharp-code

Comment: Confere tb se o C# está habilitado ai http://prntscr.com/on3jil as vezes pode ser que alguém desabilitou etc... Eu mesmo tirei um tanto de coisa que não uso para deixar o software mais leve

Comment: Pode colocar um link para a extensão?

Answer (score -3):

Eu não consegui encontrar um jeito de configurar então fui atrás de extensões.
Encontrei essa que é simples não tem nada de mais e funcionou perfeitamente:

C# Curly Formatter
https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Ironcutter24.cscurlyformatter&ssr=false#review-details

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).